# Contact Form7 compare dates with condition

Tags: jquery, wordpress, contact-form-7

I use contact form 7. I have two dates - `date-from` and `date-to`, if period is smaller than 6 months i must show one more fields with information and new dates `date-from1` and `date-from2` while the sum of dates is over 6 months. if someone can help me? I can not catch the dates and check the period between them with jquery or other method.
here is a fields :

```
 [date* date-from id:date-from] and `[date* date-to id:date-to]`
```